# Swift delegate protocol for generic class

Tags: generics, swift, delegates, protocols

I have a class, `StateMachine`, that is generic to allow for different sets of states to be implemented as, for example, an enum. I want to use a `StateMachineDelegate` protocol to notify a delegate when the state machine enters a new state.

But this doesn't work since the delegate protocol is also generic with type requirements. The error shows where the `delegate` property is declared.

```
protocol StateType: Hashable {}

protocol StateMachineDelegate: class {
    typealias S: StateType
    func stateMachine(stateMachine: StateMachine<S>, didEnterState newState: S)
}

class StateMachine<S: StateType> {
    typealias State = S

    weak var delegate: StateMachineDelegate?
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    //Protocol 'StateMachineDelegate' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

    var currentState: State {...}

    init(initialState: State) {...}

    func applyState(toState: State) -> Bool {
        ...
        currentState = toState
        delegate?.stateMachine(self, didEnterState: toState)
        ...
    }
}
```

I need to somehow associate that `StateMachineDelegate.S == S` in the `StateMachine` class, but I'm not sure how to do this, or if it's possible. I tried:

```
class StateMachine<S: StateType, D: StateMachineDelegate where D.S == S> {
    ...
    weak var delegate: D?
    ...
}
```

but then I get stuck trying to rework the protocol to properly declare the generic type of `StateMachine`. And it doesn't seem right to have to declare the type of the delegate up front when creating a `StateMachine`.

Answer (score 1):

See if this workaround is ok for your needs, it uses `@autoclosure` to get rid of a problem with recursive generic definitions:

```
class StateMachine<S: Printable, D: StateMachineDelegate where S == D.StateType> {

    var currentState: S {
        didSet {
            // The observer
            if let delegate = self.delegate {
                delegate.stateMachine(self, didEnterState: self.currentState)
            }
        }
    }

    var delegate: D?

    init(initialState: S) {
        self.currentState = initialState
    }


}


protocol StateMachineDelegate: class {
    typealias StateType: Printable

    // Workaround with autoclosure
    func stateMachine(machine: @autoclosure() -> StateMachine<StateType, Self>, didEnterState newState: StateType)
}

final class ADelegate: StateMachineDelegate {
    typealias StateType = Int
    func stateMachine(machine: @autoclosure  () -> StateMachine<StateType, ADelegate>, didEnterState newState: StateType) {
        // Need to _unbox_ the sander from the closure
        let sender = machine()
        println(newState)
        println("State from sender: \(sender.currentState)")
    }
}

let stateMachine = StateMachine<Int, ADelegate>(initialState: 24)

stateMachine.delegate = ADelegate()
stateMachine.currentState = 50
```

By the way, consider that if you get the sander, probably you don't need to get the `newState` passed.
I used `Printable` in place of `Hashable` for the example.

Answer (score 0):

I think its just a name collision problem ... try this:

```
protocol StateType: Hashable {}

protocol StateMachineDelegate: class {
    typealias State: StateType
    func stateMachine(stateMachine: StateMachine<State>, didEnterState newState: State)
}

class StateMachine<S: StateType> {
    typealias State = S

    weak var delegate: StateMachineDelegate?


    var currentState: State {...}

    init(initialState: State) {...}

    func applyState(toState: State) -> Bool {
        ...
            currentState = toState
        delegate?.stateMachine(self, didEnterState: toState)
        ...
    }
}
```

You need to declare what the name of the generic type defined in the protocol should be in the class conforming to it.

Comment: By the way, given that state machine is a good design pattern for a lot of problems, why constraining the state to be hashable? You loose the power of enums with associated values ( or at least you'll have to conform them to hashable). IMHO enums with associated values are great for state machines logics.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. I think the problem runs a bit deeper. My guess is that the compiler can't (for whatever reason) guarantee that the `StateMachineDelegate`'s type requirements will be satisfied, as `StateMachine` doesn't make any promises in that regard. If `StateMachine` included a _generic_ type parameter constrained to `StateMachineDelegate`, then it's promising that it'll be replaced with a satisfactory class at runtime (but then I end up with an odd parameter of `StateMachine<S, D>` in the delegate protocol). Perhaps it'll become possible as the language develops.

Comment: Regarding the hashable constraint, I did this because the state machine actually stores states & state transitions, and checks for their existence to determine whether a requested state change is valid. The class is a bit more complex than I showed in the question, and will get more complex as I experiment further! If associated enums are handy, it shouldn't be a problem to conform them to `Hashable`, like you suggest.

Comment: Ups sorry, playground crashing so frequently that it stopped giving me the error :-/ Isn't it more correct if the delegate defines an alias with regard to the state machine type, instead of the state type? ... Sadly trying this way is a constant crash of playground and editor assistant to me :-S

Comment: SourceKit is crashing constantly for me too... clearly this is giving the compiler as much of a headache as me! You're probably right about defining the state machine as the typealias (although I still need to reference a `State` type in the delegate method, so might use: `typealias StateMachine: Stateful`, then `protocol Stateful { typealias State }` and `class StateMachine<S: StateType>: Stateful {...}`... then in the delegate can refer to `StateMachine.State`). But the delegate protocol would still be generic (has an associated type requirement), so doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: As a workaround you could explore the possibility of assigning an optional function to the state machine instead of a delegate :-/