# Have a generic object as a class member without specifying type using protocol or class

Tags: swift, generics, swift3, protocols

So the idea is:
I have a subclass (of NSView for instance) called an `AmazingViewClass` and I want to store a member of a generic type called `AmazingData`.

`AmazingData` is defined as:

```
protocol AmazingDataType {}

class  AmazingData <x:CustomStringConvertible, y:Hashable>: AmazingDataType {
    var xValues: x
    var yValues: y
    init(xValues: x, yValues: y) {
        self.xValues = xValues
        self.yValues = yValues
    }
}
```

Then I have a protocol that can only be applied to NSView subclass:

```
protocol AmazingViewProtocol  {
    associatedtype View: NSView = Self //AmazingViewProtocol can only be applied to NSView
    associatedtype myType: AmazingDataType //so that data can only be of type AmazingDataType
    var data: myType! { get set }
}
```

And finally I declare a class **AmazingViewClass**

```
class AmazingView: NSView, AmazingViewProtocol {

}
```

However, it doesn't allow me to do that, requiring to specify the type of **data** variable like so:

```
class AmazingView: NSView, AmazingViewProtocol {
    typealias myType = AmazingData <Int, Int>
    var data: AmazingData <Int, Int>!
}
```

What I want to avoid is declaring the `AmazingViewClass` as `AmazingViewClass <Type,Type>` and set the **data** to any type I want later after initializing **AmazingView** like:

```
let data = AmazingData<Int, Double>()
... 
var aView = AmazingView(frame: CGRect...)
aView.data = data
```

So is there any way to achieve it? Or the compiler will never allow me to create a class without explicitly specifying a type of a generic variable?

Comment: So you want to be able to specify for each `AmazingView` instance the type of `myType`? Basically you want to conform your class to the protocols associated type requirement in a generic way?

Comment: I want to instantiate  an AmazingView() and then later set the data property of any type. But at the time of instantiating AmazingView I want to avoid declaring any type

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, no, you can't do this. See [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39469388/swift-generalized-existentials), [2](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md)