# What does "existential type" mean in Swift?

Tags: swift, type-theory

I am reading [Swift Evolution proposal 244 (Opaque Result Types)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0244-opaque-result-types.md#introduction) and don't understand what the following means:

> ... existential type ...
>
> One could compose these transformations by
> using the ***existential type*** Shape instead of generic arguments, but
> doing so would imply more dynamism and runtime overhead than may be
> desired.

Comment: Have a look at [Exploring existential types in Swift](https://medium.com/@dogwith1eye/exploring-existential-types-with-swift-c86142d7bd1c)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

An example of a protocol that can be used as an existential type is given in the evolution proposal itself:

```
protocol Shape {
  func draw(to: Surface)
}
```

An example of using `protocol Shape` as an existential type would look like

```swift
func collides(with: any Shape) -> Bool
```

as opposed to using a generic argument `Other`:

```swift
func collides(with: some Shape) -> Bool
```

Since `some` keyword for parameter types became available only in Swift 5.7, in older versions this generic "non-existential" version code could be only written in a more verbose way as

```swift
func collides<Other: Shape>(with: Other) -> Bool
```

Important to note here that the `Shape` protocol is not an existential type by itself, only using it in ["protocols-as-types"](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID275) context as above "creates" an existential type from it. See [this post from the member of Swift Core Team](https://forums.swift.org/t/improving-the-ui-of-generics/22814):

> Also, protocols currently do double-duty as the spelling for existential types, but this relationship has been a common source of confusion.

This was also the motivation for introducing the `any` keyword that marks an existential type explicitly.

Also, citing the [Swift Generics Evolution](https://www.timekl.com/blog/2019/04/14/swift-generics-evolution/) article (I recommend reading the whole thing, which explains this in more details):

> The best way to distinguish a protocol type from an existential type is to look at the context. Ask yourself: when I see a reference to a protocol name like Shape, is it appearing at a type level, or at a value level? Revisiting some earlier examples, we see:
>
> ```swift
> func addShape<T: Shape>() -> T
> // Here, Shape appears at the type level, and so is referencing the protocol type
>
> var shape: any Shape = Rectangle()
> // Here, Shape appears at the value level, and so creates an existential type
> ```

## Deeper dive

Why is it called an "existential"? I never saw an unambiguous confirmation of this, but I assume that the feature is inspired by languages with more advanced type systems, e.g. consider [Haskell's existential types](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type):

```hs
class Buffer -- declaration of type class `Buffer` follows here

data Worker x y = forall b. Buffer b => Worker {
  buffer :: b, 
  input :: x, 
  output :: y
}
```

which is roughly equivalent to this Swift snippet (if we assume that Swift's protocols more or less represent Haskell's type classes):

```swift
protocol Buffer {}

struct Worker<X, Y> {
  let buffer: any Buffer
  let input: X
  let output: Y
}
```

Note that the Haskell example used `forall` [quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification) here. You could read this as "for all types that conform to the `Buffer` type class ("protocol" in Swift) values of type `Worker` would have exactly the same types as long as their `X` and `Y` type parameters are the same". Thus, given

```
extension String: Buffer {}
extension Data: Buffer {}
```

values `Worker(buffer: "", input: 5, output: "five")` and `Worker(buffer: Data(), input: 5, output: "five")` would have exactly the same type.

This is a powerful feature, which allows things such as heterogenous collections, and can be used in a lot more places where you need to "erase" an original type of a value and "hide" it under an existential type. Like all powerful features it can be abused and can make code less type-safe and/or less performant, so should be used with care.

If you want even a deeper dive, check out [Protocols with Associated Types (PATs)](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-what-are-protocols-with-associated-types/), which currently can't be used as existentials for various reasons. There are also a few [Generalized Existentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39469388/swift-generalized-existentials) proposals being pitched more or less regularly, but nothing concrete as of Swift 5.3. In fact, the original [Opaque Result Types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0244-opaque-result-types.md) proposal linked by the OP can solve some of the problems caused by use of PATs and significantly alleviates lack of generalized existentials in Swift.

Comment: Well, we’ve got our opaque result types now, but they didn’t alleviate much of anything.

Comment: Certainly SwiftUI API would be much cumbersome without opaque result types, similarly this feature is quite handy at times when using Combine.

Comment: @MaxDesiatov true, but it is basically still a hack around the absence of existentials. It is really frustrating that a protocol cannot conform to `EnvironmentObjetct`. This means I have to pass concrete implementations, basically killing "protocol oriented programing".

Comment: @MaxDesiatov this is a really well-explained answer, thank you. And in the absence (still to this day) of generalized existentials, is type-erasure the only go-to solution? What if the type-erasure "workaround" presents its own limits, such as the impossibility of adding init and/or static methods to type-erased PAT?

Comment: I think you should have a look at protocol witnesses approach, which may be suitable workaround for the lack of generalized existentials, described in this presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BVkbWXcFS4

Comment: Can't we just use `Shape` insread of `any Shape`?

Comment: For now you can write `Shape` instead of `any Shape`, but according to the proposal that introduced `any` ([SE-0335](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0335-existential-any.md#proposed-solution)) this will become an error in Swift 6. Some of the reasoning is that this will underscore the fact that existentials introduce a performance overhead due to boxing and most of the time you should be using generics instead of existentials.

Comment: in the answer it quoted: "> var shape: any Shape = Rectangle()
 // Here, Shape appears at the value level, and so creates an existential type".
however if you look at swift declaration format copied from swift org:"let <#constant name#>: <#type#> = <#expression#>", clearly the `Shape` is used in a place where a type supposed to be, how does it make sense that "Shape appears at the value level".

Comment: Excellent answer. You said 'var shape: any Shape'. Can you elaborate the term 'value level'? Just trying to get my jargon right...

Answer (score 13):

### Short Answer

I'm sure you've already used existentials a lot before without noticing it.

A re-worded answer of Max is that for:

```
var rec: Shape = Rectangle() // Example A
```

only `Shape` properties can be accessed.

While for:

```
func addShape<T: Shape>() -> T // Example B
```

Any property of `T` can be accessed. Because `T` adopts `Shape` then all properties of `Shape` can also be accessed as well.

**The first example is an existential the second is not. An alternate naming of an existential is 'protocol as type'**

And as Max said in his answer:

> "it's important to note here that the Shape protocol is not an existential type by itself, only using it in "protocols-as-types" context as above "creates" an existential type from it"

### Example of real code:

```
protocol Shape {
  var width: Double { get }
  var height: Double { get }
}

struct Rectangle: Shape {
  var width: Double
  var height: Double
  var area: Double
}

let rec1: Shape = Rectangle(width: 1, height: 2, area: 2)

rec1.area // ❌
```

However:

```
let rec2 = Rectangle(width: 1, height: 2, area: 2)
func addShape<T: Shape>(_ shape: T) -> T {
    print(type(of: shape)) // Rectangle
    return shape
}
let rec3 = addShape(rec2)

print(rec3.area) // ✅
```

---

I'd argue that for most Swift users, we all understand Abstract class and Concrete class. This extra jargon makes it slightly confusing.

The trickiness is that with the 2nd example, to the compiler, the type you return isn't `Shape`, it's `Rectangle` i.e. the function signature *transforms* to this:

```
func addShape(_ shape: Rectangle) -> Rectangle {
```

This is only possible because of *(constrained) generics*.

Yet for `rec: Shape = Whatever()` to the compiler the type is `Shape` regardless of the assigning type. <-- Box Type

tldr when it comes to protocols, you're either using

- constrained generics
- existential

and for the most part you don't care about the differences between the two. It's just that in some more low level swift protocol discussions the term existential comes up as a way to be more specific about certain Swift protocol usage.

### Why is it named Existential?

The term "existential" in computer science and programming is borrowed from philosophy, where it refers to the concept of existence and being. In the context of programming, "existential" is used to describe a type that represents the existence of any specific type, without specifying which type it is.

The term is used to reflect the idea that, by wrapping a value in an existential type, you are abstracting away its *specific* type and only *acknowledging its existence*.

In other words, an existential type provides a way to handle values of *different* types in a *unified* way, while ignoring their specific type information†. This allows you to work with values in a more generic and flexible manner, which can be useful in many situations, such as when creating collections of heterogeneous values, or when working with values of unknown or dynamic types.

The other day I took my kid to an  shop. She asked what are you having, and I didn't know the flavor I picked, so I didn't say it's strawberry flavored nor chocolate, I just said "I'm having an ice-cream". She wasn't happy with my answer...

I just specified that it's an ice-cream without saying its flavor. My daughter could no longer determine if it was Red, or Brown. If it was having a fruit flavor or not. **I gave her existential-like information.**

Had I told her it's a chocolate, then I would have gave her specific information. Which is then not existential.

In short existential means we know something about the type, but not everything. Things are a bit vague/incomplete. Like we don't know its associated type, or static type information.

†: In Example B, we're not ignoring the specific type information.

## Quiz

```
1. var x: [SomeProtocol]
2. var y: SomeProtocol = SomeClass()
3. func jump(item: SomeProtocol) {...}
4. func jump(item: any SomeProtocol) {...}
5. func hype<T: SomeProtocol) {...}
```

> 1,2,3,4 are existential, because `someProtocol` is being used as a type.
>
>  4 is an **explicit** existential. See [this proposal for more](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0335-existential-any.md#proposed-solution).
>
>  5 is a constrained (generic) type. See [Generics - Type Constraints](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/generics/#Type-Constraints)

After reading my answer, I suggest you go and re-read Max's answer. It might take 5-6 times over a period of a time to fully understand.

<sub>Special thanks to a friend who helped me come up with this answer</sub>

Comment: very well crafted answer!

Comment: Like your answer!

Answer (score 9):

I feel like it's worth adding something about why the phrase is important in Swift. And in particular, I think almost always, Swift is talking about "existential containers". They talk about "existential types", but only really with reference to "stuff that is stored in an existential container". So what is an "existential container"?

As I see it, the key thing is, if you have a variable that you're passing as a parameter or using locally, etc. and you define the type of the variable as `Shape` then Swift has to do some things under the hood to make it work and that's what they are (obliquely) referring to.

If you think about defining a function in a library/framework module that you're writing that is publicly available and takes for example the parameters `public func myFunction(shape1: Shape, shape2: Shape, shape1Rotation: CGFloat?) -> Shape`... imagine it (optionally) rotates shape1, "adds" it to shape2 somehow (I leave the details up to your imagination) then returns the result. Coming from other OO languages, we instinctively think that we understand how this works... the function must be implemented only with members available in the `Shape` protocol.

But the question is for the compiler, how are the parameters represented in memory? Instinctively, again, we think... it doesn't matter. When someone writes a new program that uses your function at some point in the future, they decide to pass their own shapes in and define them as `class Dinosaur: Shape` and `class CupCake: Shape`. As part of defining those new classes, they will have to write implementations of all the methods in `protocol Shape`, which might be something like `func getPointsIterator() -> Iterator<CGPoint>`. That works just fine for classes. The calling code defines those classes, instantiates objects from them, passes them into your function. Your function must have something like a vtable (I think Swift calls it a witness table) for the `Shape` protocol that says "if you give me an instance of a Shape object, I can tell you exactly where to find the address of the `getPointsIterator` function". The instance pointer will point to a block of memory on the stack, the start of which is a pointer to the class metadata (vtables, witness tables, etc.) So the compiler can reason about how to find any given method implementation.

But what about value types? Structs and enums can have just about any format in memory, from a one byte Bool to a 500 byte complex nested struct. These are usually passed on the stack or registers on function calls for efficiency. (When Swift exactly knows the type, all code can be compiled knowing the data format and passed on the stack or in registers, etc.)

Now you can see the problem. How can Swift compile the function `myFunction` so it will work with *any* possible future value type/struct defined in any code? As I understand it, this is where "existential containers" come in.

The simplest approach would be that any function that takes parameters of one of these "existential types" (types defined just by conforming to a Protocol) must insist that the calling code "box" the value type... that it store the value in a special reference counted "box" on the heap and pass a pointer to this (with all the usual ARC retain/release/autorelease/ownership rules) to your function when the function takes a parameter of type `Shape`.

Then when a new, weird and wonderful, type is written by some code author in the future, compiling the methods of `Shape` would have to include a way to accept "boxed" versions of the type. Your `myFunction` would always handle these "existential types" by handling the box and everything works. I would guess that C# and Java do something like this (boxing) if they have the same problem with non class types (Int, etc.)?

The thing is that for a lot of value types, this can be very inefficient. After all, we are compiling mostly for 64 bit architecture, so a couple of registers can handle 8 bytes, enough for many simple structures. So Swift came up with a compromise (again I might be a bit inaccurate on this, I'm giving my idea of the mechanism... feel free to correct). They created "existential containers" that are always 4 pointers in size. 16 bytes on a "normal" 64 bit architecture (most CPUs that run Swift these days).

If you define a struct that conforms to a protocol and it contains 12 bytes or less, then it is stored in the existential container directly. The last 4 byte pointer is a pointer to the type information/witness tables/etc. so that `myFunction` can find an address for any function in the `Shape` protocol (just like in the classes case above). If your struct/enum is larger than 12 bytes then the 4 pointer value points to a boxed version of the value type. Obviously this was considered an optimum compromise, and seems reasonable... it will be passed around in 4 registers in most cases or 4 stack slots if "spilled".

I think the reason the Swift team end up mentioning "existential containers" to the wider community is because it then has implications for various ways of using Swift. One obvious implication is performance. There's a sudden performance drop when using functions in this way if the structs are > 12 bytes in size.

Another, more fundamental, implication I think is that protocols can be used as parameters only if they don't have protocol or Self requirements... they are not generic. Otherwise you're into generic function definitions which is different. That's why we sometimes need to change things like: `func myFunction(shape: Shape, reflection: Bool) -> Shape` into something like `func myFunction<S:Shape>(shape: S, reflection: Bool) -> S`. They are implemented in very different ways under the hood.

Comment: If I know that only classes will conform to my `Shape` protocol, does it mean that that adding `any` in front of `Shape` will make things less performant or not? I mean do classes get boxed or not?