# Why Swift's Combine's map returns Publishers.Map<Self, T> instead of <T, Error>

Tags: ios, swift, combine

My request resulting in AnyPublisher

```
let foo: AnyPublisher<API.Response, API.Error> = APIClient.get(API.Endpoints.Demo)
```

now I would like to map the value of this publisher to array of string,
`message` in API.Response is of type `[String : [String]]`, so my try is

```
foo.map { $0.message.map { $0.key } }
```

at this point I would expect I would end up with `AnyPublisher<[String], API.Error>`, or just any other publisher but parametrized to `<[String], API.Error>`,
instead I end up with `Publishers.Map<AnyPublisher<API.Response, API.Error>, [String]>`.

```
func map<T>(_ transform: @escaping (Self.Output) -> T) -> Publishers.Map<Self, T>
```

The docs above for `.map` function are correct, but why is it working like that - why would someone expect the map to keep the previous publisher type but somehow nested inside there. I can't figure it out, any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are used to other ReactiveX-style libraries, or you're used to a language (like Java or Kotlin or Scala) where objects are always heap-allocated, Combine types can be quite a shock.

Because `Publishers.Map` is generic over the type of its upstream publisher (in this case, `AnyPublisher<API.Response, API.Error>`), it can store its upstream publisher inline, without needing to wrap the upstream in [an existential container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867602/what-does-existential-type-mean-in-swift) or otherwise heap-allocate storage for the upstream.

`Map` also optimizes consecutive uses of the `map` operator. The Combine framework defines [a `map` operator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/map(_:)-99evh) for all `Publisher`s, and [`Map` inherits that](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/map/map(_:)-2aywq). But `Map` also defines [a more specialized `map` operator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/map/map(_:)-uzk4) which coalesces consecutive `map` operators.

Here's an example:

```
import Combine

let foo: AnyPublisher<[String: [String]], Error> = Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher()

let chained = foo
    .map { Array($0.keys) }
    .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
    .map { $0.joined(separator: ", ") }
    .map { "[\($0)]" }
print("chained", type(of: chained))
```

What's the type of `chained`? It is

```
Map<
  Filter<
    Map<
      AnyPublisher<
        Dictionary<String, Array<String>>,
        Error
      >,
      Array<String>
    >
  >,
  String
>
```

Notice two things here. There are only two `Map`s in the type, even though I used the `map` operator three times. That's because the final use of `map` uses the `Map` type's specialized `map` operator, which coalesces the two consecutive uses of `map` into a single `Map` instance.

And because `Map` and `Filter` are `struct`s, they can be store on the stack or directly inline as properties of other data types. So the value in `chained` can be stored on the stack.

In general, `Map` might need to store its `transform` function on the heap, but it doesn't also need to perform a heap allocation to store its upstream. In the example above, since none of arguments passed to `map` and `filter` close over any outside variables, Swift might be able to optimize out **all** heap allocations when creating the `chained` value.

The use of generic types here also gives the compiler more knowledge about how the `chained` value is constructed, so it might be able to perform other optimizations.

So, applying an operator to a publisher usually returns a different type of publisher. If you need to write a function that takes a publisher as an argument, this means you should make the function generic over the type of publisher. For example, every SwiftUI `View` has [an `onReceive` modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onreceive(_:perform:)#) with this signature:

```
func onReceive<P>(
    _ publisher: P,
    perform action: @escaping (P.Output) -> Void
) -> some View where P : Publisher, P.Failure == Never
```

You can pass any publisher to `onReceive`, as long as that publisher's `Failure` associated type is `Never`. So you can pass a `Map` or a `Filter` or an `AnyPublisher` to `onReceive`.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation, now the question still remains, is it possible to achieve something similar to existential containers? Problem I see with this, how one is supposed to work with Publishers types as dependencies? They should be transparent as dependencies (why would other class care if map or filter was used on the way...)