# SwiftUI concrete typed array doesn't work with ForEach

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Ok, this might be a stupid question. But i can't seem to wrap my head around this. I'm trying to achieve below scenario,

I need to have an array that accept classes/structs inherits a common protocol. The compiler is complaining "Type 'any CommonFont' cannot conform to 'Identifiable'".

```
protocol CommonFont: Identifiable {
    var name: String { get set }
    var font: Font { get set }
    var id: String { get }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    private struct CustomFont1: Identifiable, CommonFont {
        var name: String
        var font: Font
        var id: String { name }
    }
    
    
    private let namedFonts: [any CommonFont] = [
        CustomFont1(name: "Large Title", font: .largeTitle),
        CustomFont1(name: "Title", font: .title),
        CustomFont1(name: "Headline", font: .headline),
        CustomFont1(name: "Body", font: .body),
        CustomFont1(name: "Caption", font: .caption)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(namedFonts) { namedFont in // <- The error throws here
                Text(namedFont.name)
                    .font(namedFont.font)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: “any” isn’t concrete, you need concrete types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a "concrete typed array." It's an existentially (`any`) type array. Existentials do not conform to protocols. `any CommonFont` does not itself conform to CommonFont, and so also does not itself conform to Identifiable.

In this case, the only impact is that you can't rely on the Identifiable constructor here. You have to pass `id` directly:

```
ForEach(namedFonts, id: \.id) { namedFont in 
                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Im familiar with existentials as much as I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69508305/5175709). yet wasn’t aware: `any someProtocol` also means an existential. It makes sense though. As you don’t know the concrete type. All you know is that it’s conforms to a protocol. What I don’t understand is “ Existentials do not conform to protocols.” like don’t elements of that array have to be of type CommonFont? If so doesn’t it mean they conform to the protocol? Or while each element does conform, to the compiler, it’s just `any CommonFont` which then I’m not sure what promise it makes/fulfills

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: See Hamish's semi-canonical explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/97337  The short form, however, is that  `any CommonFont` is a **box** that wrap something that conforms to CommonFont, but that box does not **itself** conform. It just passes methods to the thing in the box. Since a protocol can include things the box could not pass along (in particular it could require type-level, rather than instance-level features such as `init` or `static`), Swift currently never permits the existential to conform itself. Someday it may allow it in those cases where it is possible.

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier for the explanation, It makes total sense. Cheers.